# List chromatic number and edge coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that $\chi_l(G)>c\log \chi'(G)$ for every graph $G$ and for some fixed constant $c$.

Here $\chi_l(G)$ refers to list chromatic number and $\chi'(G)$ refers to chromatic index.

My thought: So we know that there exist a bound between chromatic number and list chromatic number which states: $\chi_l(G)> \chi(G)$. And $\chi(G) \le 1/2 (1+ \sqrt {1 +8|E(G)|})$ I was planing to use this bound and derive the inequality. But I am unable to do so. I am aware of Vizing's theorem and Brooks' theorem that give similar kind of bound for both respectively. But I am still stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound is false.

Consider $G = K_{1,n}$. Then $\chi'(G) = n$ while $\chi_l(G) = 2$, for any $n$. So no inequality of the type you describe can hold.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with a complete bipartite graph and it was also not satisfying the strict bound but I thought I did wrong

Comment: With the complete bipartite graph, there's no problem, actually: $\chi'(K_{n,n}) = n$ and $\chi_l(K_{n,n}) = (1 + o(1)) \log_2 n$.

Comment: More generally: since $\chi'(G)$ is either $\Delta(G)$ or $\Delta(G)+1$, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree, the claim you were trying to prove is that $\chi'(G) > c \log \Delta(G)$ for some $c$. That's false, but a related bound is true: [a paper of Alon](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/degch1.pdf) shows that $\chi'(G) > (\frac12 - o(1)) \log \delta(G)$, where $\delta(G)$ is the **minimum** degree.

Comment: Oh! I was not aware of this bound. Thanks I will look into it .